# Building Python extension module with distutils

Tags: c++, python, gcc, distutils

I'm using distutils to build a Python extension module written in C++.  The problem I have is that in order to compile the extension module, I need to link with a certain shared library.  This requires setting an additional compiler flag.  So, I searched through the Python docs and found out about the `extra_compile_args` property of the `Extension` object.  So I tried the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('test', sources = ['test.cpp'])
module.extra_compile_args = ['--std=c++0x', '-l mylib'];
setup(name = 'test', version = '1.0', ext_modules = [module])
```

This seems to compile, except when I import my module in Python it throws an `ImportError` exception due to an undefined symbol. So, apparently the library didn't link properly.  So I tried writing a throw away C++ program which linked with the shared library, and it ran fine.  Then I realized something really odd is going on with `distutils`, because if I add a compile argument that links to a bogus library name, distutils just compiles everything with no problem:

```
module.extra_compile_args = ['--std=c++0x', '-l some_fake_library'];
```

When I run `setup.py build`, the build runs with no errors!

So, what's going on here?  How can I compile an extension module that requires linkage to a shared library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually a special option for that.

For example:

```
libraries=["rt"]
```

You leave off the option and lib parts.

Answer (score 3):

One of the purposes of distutils is to make your code not dependent on a single compiler. Your "-l somelib" looks like it's meant to work with GCC (even though it should be "-lsomelib", no space). This is why you use the `libraries` option to the `Extension` class. Distutils will then pass the appropriate link command to whatever compiler it's using.

You can also look at the actual build commands distutils is using and execute them yourself to see what is going wrong.