# Install precompiled python extension with distutils

Tags: python, distutils

How can I specify an arbitrary set of files (non necessarily .py files) so that they are distributed and installed just like normal Python modules?

#### Some background

I am using distutils to distribute and install my Python library.  One of the modules in this library imports a 3rd-party Python extension called bpy.so (this is a [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) module).  The bpy.so extension requires some other files, as well.  I want to distribute and install bpy.so and the additional required files with my library.

One way to do this is by specifying all of the extra files as data_files to setup().  However, I don't know how to reliably specify the same installation directory as is used for my pure python modules (e.g. /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages).
I can distribute the extra files by creating a MANIFEST.in file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760356/building-python-extension-module-with-distutils)), but I also want to *install* the files.

Comment: Do [the docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#including-data-files) help?

Comment: Those are the docs for setuptools, of which I was previously unaware.  (See mac's answer below.)  I was using distutils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would suggest to use setuptools on top of distutils.**

[This](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html) is a good reference document to get started with it. The advantage of using setuptools is that it has a few nice features like the possibility to include all files under a given directory (package) automatically or according to filters. [This](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#including-data-files) is the section of the above document dealing with this specific aspect.

HTH!

PS: distutils' current situation/limitations are the source of much complain from most of its users. It seems [a new generation of the library](http://packages.python.org/Distutils2/) is on its way though!

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  This appears to be exactly what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: package_data was backported to distutils in Python 2.4.  You don’t need to switch to setuptools just for them.  (There are good and bad things when using setuptools.)